# Find coordinates of the centers of the two possible regular $n$-sided polygons with two given points as adjacent vertices

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

This is a short question, but I’m not quite sure what the answer is.

> Given two points in the real plane, is there a way to find the coordinates of the centers of the two possible regular n-sided polygons with the given points as adjacent vertices? (Given some random n bigger than 2).

It seems like the answer will involve some trigonometry and simple pre-calc but I haven’t been able to work it out.

Comment: yes as the central angle between the two is $360\over n$ degrees, forcing $90-{180\over n}$ degree angles from both ...

Comment: But what would be the coordinates of either center in that case?

Comment: average the coordinates to find the midpoint and find the distance you must go in either direction perpendicular via trig.

Comment: Ah right, thank you!